Automatically scroll up the lazy column to display the full height of the card when expanded
This code does not work as expected. I want lazy column to automatically scroll up to display the entire height of the card when expanded.
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

LazyColumn(
    state = listState
) {
    itemsIndexed(items) { index, item ->
        ExpandableCard(
            item = item,
            isExpanded = expandedCardsStates[item.id] ?: false,
            onCardClicked = {
                viewModel.expandedState(item.id)
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    listState.animateScrollToItem(index = index)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

Here's how it appears with this code when I expand the last card:

Here's the expected behaviour:


Using animateScrollToItem is not going to give you satisfactory results. It will attempt to scroll the LazyColumn so that the given item is at the top of the LazyColumn. If the item is the last one on screen, this will result in a stuttering animation. Another problem is that the scrolling might already be performed while the animation is still in progress, resulting in a not fully visible item.
What you probably want is to only scroll the LazyColumn if the expanded item is not fully visible on the screen. To detect these cases, add a onGoballyPositioned Modifier on the AnimatedVisibility:
@Composable
fun ExpandableCard(/** ... **/ ) {

    var isFullyVisible by remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)  // stores whether the expanded content is fully visible on screen
    }
    var contentHeightPx by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)  // stores the height of the expanded content
    }

    Card(
        //...
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            // ...

            AnimatedVisibility(
                modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                    val (width, height) = coordinates.size
                    val (x1, y1) = coordinates.positionInRoot()
                    val x2 = x1 + width
                    val y2 = y1 + height
                    val screenWidth: Float = configuration.screenWidthDp.toPx
                    val screenHeight: Float = configuration.screenHeightDp.toPx
                    isFullyVisible = (x1 >= 0 && y1 >= 0) && (x2 <= screenWidth && y2 <= screenHeight)
                    contentHeightPx = coordinates.size.height.toFloat()
                },
                visible = isExpanded,
                enter = expandVertically() + fadeIn(),
                exit = shrinkVertically() + fadeOut()
            ) {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}

You need to add the following extension function:
val Number.toPx
    get() = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        this.toFloat(),
        Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
    )

Next, we need to make sure that the scrolling is only performed after the animation of AnimatedVisibility was completed. We need to add a seperate callback function to the ExpandableCard Composable. Also, we change the function return type of onCardClicked from Job to Unit:
@Composable
fun ExpandableCard(/** ... **/ onCardClicked: () -> Unit, onCardExpanded: (Float) -> Job) {
    //...
}

Then, we call the onCardExpanded once the expand animation was finished:
AnimatedVisibility(
    //...
) {

    val animatedVisibilityScope = this

    LaunchedEffect(animatedVisibilityScope.transition.isRunning) {
        if (!animatedVisibilityScope.transition.isRunning &&
            animatedVisibilityScope.transition.currentState == EnterExitState.Visible
        ) {
            if (!isFullyVisible) {
                // If the content is not fully visible, scroll LazyColumn
                onCardExpanded(contentHeightPx)
            }
        }
    }

    // expanded content
}

Finally, apply the scroll in the LazyColumn:
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp, top = 20.dp),
    state = listState
) {
    itemsIndexed(items) { index, item ->
        ExpandableCard(
            engagementPointItem = item,
            isExpanded = expandedCardsStates[item.id] ?: false,
            onCardClicked = {
                viewModel.toggleExpandedState(item.id)
            },
            onCardExpanded = { scrollAmount ->
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    listState.animateScrollBy(scrollAmount + 50)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

Output:


thanks, but the cards above the screen when opened expand incorrectly
note that the content in the card is long (Approximately 10 lines)

What do you mean by "the card above the screen"? Can you share a video of the problem? Also, the length of the Card content shouldn't matter, as the required height is calculated dynamically. It will scroll as much as the height of the content is.

in the video that you sent, when opening first card displayed (card number 31 for example) it is opened up instead of down. this is done in the wrong way in some cases like this case

can you share your code in github please?

I just saw that there was one extension function missing in my answer, I edited my post. Also, here is the link to the Snippet: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3721931 For simplicity, I used a Column instead of a LazyColumn. That way, I don't have to use a ViewModel to store the exanded / collapsed state.

it's work! thanks alot
